# apps that uses dual core processor

Tags: android, mobile, processor

There are dual core and now quad core phones in market. However i really don't know what kind of apps does truly makes use of the feature. Can anyone provide some information on the apps that can really make use the power of dual -quad cores in mobile devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of having dual,quad or more processing is not for specific apps to use it.
It just means having more processing speed available at hand, which will only be used when completely necessary. 
For example, when there is a process that can be handled by one core, which is usually the case for most apps, the other cores aren't necessary. But there are high end games or more than one process that have to be run, which need lots of calculations at a given time, other cores may also be used, if there is room for improvement in the first core.

Comment: Thanks NoviceDroid: Yes for apps and games one core itself is enough except for some high end games as you mentioned. How do i say my app uses dual core if my app spawns N number of threads for processing different functionality of the app. it all depends on how mobile processes?

Comment: Glad i could help. not so sure about the depths of this topic though